# transform command line docker to Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have this dockers commands

> 1 - docker run -itp 3000:3000 --expose 3000 --name ead-courses-service
>   -v /home/dizie/Projects/node/ead-project-api/ead-courses:/home/ead-courses
>   -w /home/ead-courses --link mongodb node-service npm start
>
> 2 - docker run -itp 3001:3001 --name ead-proofs-service -v
>   /home/dizie/Projects/node/ead-project-api/ead-proofs:/home/ead-proofs
>   -w /home/ead-proofs --link ead-courses-service,mongodb node-service npm start
>
> 3 - docker run -itp 3002:3002 --name ead-students-service -v
>   /home/dizie/Projects/node/ead-project-api/ead-students:/home/ead-students
>   -w /home/ead-students --link mongodb node-service npm start

I like to execute with mode easier.

Is possible?

Example, Dockerfile or docker-compose.

Comment: docker-compose file would work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this help. If you are using Windows then just create a `.bat` file and put all your commands in it. You just have execute this `.bat` file and all your command will get executed.

If you are using unix/linux OS then create a `.sh` file and put all your commands in it.

As these are plain commands these should help.

Answer (score -1):

A first approach just to get you started woudl be to:

- run those images (you get three containers)
- docker commit those containers (you get three images representing what was running)
- apply to those images [`CenturyLinkLabs/dockerfile-from-image`](https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/dockerfile-from-image), which will generate a Dockerfile per image.

Comment: This approach will not work. You can not publish ports (not to be confused with exposing ports) and mount any host volume from the dockerfile. These things have to be defines when the container is started from either cmd-line or dockerfile

Comment: Agreed. This was to get the OP started. The resulting Dockerfile will need to be adapted/completed.